# # in paramertized route breaks Aurelia routes

Tags: aurelia

We have sample app with router configuration defined as follows. "id" parameter in the user details route can have # in its value, such as /users/#abc. We can navigate to the user details view from users view whose "id" is #abc with no problem. However, when refreshing the details page, it goes back to the users view. Is there a way to escape character "#"?

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],       name: 'home',       moduleId: 'home/index' },
      { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index',   nav: true },
      { route: 'users/:id', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' }
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a documented bug in the router. See https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/424 and https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/435

Answer (score 0):

Since template parameters are not being encoded/decoded, they are very restrictive. Basically, this means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Note, that this is not from documentation, but my observation.

If you need to pass any arbitrary data, just use query parameters. To do that, set up router *without* defining template parameter.

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],       name: 'home',       moduleId: 'home/index' },
      { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index',   nav: true },
      { route: 'user', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' }
    ]);
  }
}
```

You don't have to change anything else (navigation, parameters in activate, etc.) In this way, upon navigation, it'll be turned into query parameter:

```
router.navigateToRoute('userDetail', { id: '#user123' });
```

This will result in url: `http://myserver/#user?id=%23user123`.

Comment: That is a good alternative. However, our application do have more child routes under userDetail. I think I can base64 encode the id. That will solve the problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if route `user` has its own sub-router, the parameter will be added to the query. The drawback is that it'l sit at the end of the URL.
I know, it is more understandable to follow the hierarchy:
`user/myUser/childroute` vs. `user/childRoute?userId=myUser`